# My wacom pen out of sync on all graphics app

Tags: calibration, wacom

I installed lot of drawing software:

- MediBang Paint Pro
- Inkscape
- GimPhoto
- Krita
- MyPaint

but then my pen started out of sync on those apps (cursor shows on about 400 pixel more right and 300 pixel higher), even after I start doing *Tablet PC Calibration* (in the control panel).

It doesn't happened on another Windows program (mspaint, windows explorer), only on those software. How can I fix this?

I'm using Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga on Windows 8.1.

Comment: This one time, I had the same thing happen and then I found out that my touch setting was enabled and my palm was offsetting my pointer. Took me a bit to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Installing this [Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga WinTab Driver](http://support.lenovo.com/id/id/downloads/ds041384) solves the problem.